# ActiveAdmin (Rails) empty class attribute for custom index table rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am using ActiveAdmin to render an index table for a model.

The config looks like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  index do
    selectable_column
    column :username
    column "Email" do |u|
      raw "<span title='#{u.email}'>#{truncate(u.email, length: 14)}</span>"
    end
  end
end
```

The rendered HTML for the "email" TD looks like this:

```
  <td class=""><span title="useremail@example.com">useremail...</span></td>
```

I have tried passing class: 'foo' before the block and a few things like that but none have worked.

All of the columns that are not being created with the block syntax are getting a class attribute equal to the field name.

How do I set the class for the TD when using a block to render the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to override build_table_cell method, 
you can take needed code here https://gist.github.com/3995962

put it to initializers folder.

now you can use it like

```
column(:status, :sortable => 'enabled', :class=>'status') do |row|
        #some logic 
     end
```